# Problems with include

Tags: symfony, twig

i have a lot of time programming in PHP, but im doing my first steps in Symfony.
Im try write Twigg templates, i have a public template in app/Resources/view/public.html.twig.
This file contains: http://pastebin.com/T1KGMfXL.
Now, in CloudBundle, have a base.html.twig:

```
{% extends '::public.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}
<div class="login_page">
    <div class="login_box">
        {% block content %} {% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And the content in another twig file. For example, login.html.twig
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

```
{% block content %}
....
{% endblock %}
```

In the Controller, when an user try http://cloud.man.local/app.php/login:

```
public function staticAction($sitio)
    {
        // in this case, $sitio contains "login"
        return $this->render("CloudBundle:Default:$sitio.html.twig");
    }
```

So, the problem is that, only shows the footer, not show the content.
Any ideas ?.

Comment: Could you please rephrase the last question? I didn't what's the problem.

Comment: show the code of login.html.twig file and how you extended the base file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to override a block which is inside another block, so in your case I think you should try this in the another twig files:

```
{% block main %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% block content %} YOur content {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/parent.html

Hope it's helpful.

Best regard.